# Memorylessness of the geometric distribution: Why are my equations wrong?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was trying to get used to the memorylessness of the geometric distribution and came up with the following (flawed) equations:

If $X$ is a geometric random variable with parameter $p$, we have
\begin{align*}
p &= 1 - (1-p)\\
&= 1 - \text{Pr}[X\geq 2] \\
&= 1 - \text{Pr}[X\geq k + 2 \mid X \geq k ] \\
&= \text{Pr}[X < k + 2 \mid X \geq k].
\end{align*}

This should be correct. However, when we now compute the conditional probability, we obtain
\begin{align*}
p &= \text{Pr}[X < k + 2 \mid X \geq k] \\
&= \frac{\text{Pr}[X < k+2 \cap X \geq k]}{\text{Pr}[X \geq k]} \\
&= \frac{\text{Pr}[X = k \cup X = k+1]}{\text{Pr}[X \geq k]} \\
&= \frac{\text{Pr}[X = k] + \text{Pr}[X = k+1]}{\text{Pr}[X \geq k]} \\
&= \frac{p\cdot(1-p)^{k-1} + p \cdot (1-p)^k}{(1-p)^{k-1}} \\
&= p + p \cdot (1-p),
\end{align*}

which is of course wrong, unless $p = 1$ or $p = 0$.

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: try plugging in 1 for k in the first derivation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have confused the two different conventions for the geometric distribution, with values starting at $0$ or at $1$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)). For the second equality in your first equation, you seem to be assuming the convention where the values start at $1$, whereas the third equality is correct if the values start at $0$. If you want to stick with the distribution with values starting at $1$, the memorylessness property should be $\operatorname{Pr}[X\ge k+2\mid X\ge k]=\operatorname{Pr}[X\gt2]$.

Answer (score 1):

The first two lines of your first sequence of equations imply that
$\mathrm{Pr}[X\geq 2] = 1-p .$
How did you conclude that this fact is true?

It is important to know why you thought this, because everything else that you wrote contradicts that fact.